# change HTML button value color where value is from onclick calling Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, styles

I use the simple button as

```
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="ajaxsubmit(this.form)" />
```

where function `ajaxsubmit()` looks like

```
function ajaxsubmit(f) {
$('#sendreq').attr("disabled", true);
$('#sendreq').val("Sending Request");
```

I want to style button onclick value (Sending Request) to change its color to red but the color of the initial button value (search) should not change

Comment: Please clarify what element you want to change the colour from. It's unclear to me. You cannot change the colour or the value attribute as this is not a displayed element.

Comment: I just want to change the color of value "sending request" to red

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS:

```
function ajaxsubmit(f) {
  $('#sendreq').attr("disabled", true);
  $('#sendreq').val("Sending Request").addClass("redbutton");
}
```

CSS (Text Color, use background-color if thats what you want. You can use any styles that should be applied):

```
.redbutton{
    color:red;
}
```

Whenever you want to remove the red text, just call `.removeClass("redbutton")` on your button element.

Comment: I am not sure why an edit was necesary - I find jQuery's chaining usefull.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#sendreq').css('background', '#FF000');
$('#sendreq').addClass('redBackground');
```

This could be done in multiple of ways! Pick and choose :)